# PostgreSQL query returns no results

Tags: postgis, postgresql

What I am trying to do is create a table contains intersections at the location where each road intersects `Roadname 1 & Roadname 2` as well as the geometry spatial data for the intersection `ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)`

But it  seems it doesn't work out l. I am pretty new to PostgreSQL, and I am wondering if there is a way to do so? The following is what I have so far.

```
Create Table roads(
    intid_ integer,
    muni text,
    alias_ text,
    roadnames text,
    geom geometry);

Insert into roads (roadnames, geom, intid_, alias_)
SELECT 
    trim(student.sc_e911slrn.prefix) || trim(student.sc_e911slrn.name) || trim(student.sc_e911slrn.suffix), 
    geom, objectid, alias
FROM student.sc_e911slrn;

--------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE type student.inter AS (
     roadnames text,
        intid_ int,
        alias_ text,
        muni text,
        ST_Intersection geometry,
        geom geometry);

--< Cursor >--------------------------------------------------------
Create function create_intersections()
    /*returns table student.intersect_roads As $method1$*/
    RETURNS table (
        roadnames text,
        intid_ int,
        alias_ text,
        muni text,
        ST_Intersection geometry,
        geom geometry) As $$

Declare
    return_intersect inter;
    rec_road Record;
    cur_road Cursor()
        For Select intid_, geom, roadnames
        From student.roads;

Begin
    Open cur_road();

    Loop
        fetch cur_road into rec_road;
        exit when not found;

        If ST_Touches(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom) AND
            rec_road.geom != student.roads.geom AND 
            rec_road.intid_ != student.roads.intid_

        Then Update student.intersect_road
             Set st_intersection = ST_Intersection (rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom),
                 intid_ = rec_road.intid_,
                 intersections = rec_road.roadnames|| ' & ' || student.raods.roadnames,
                 alias_ = rec_road.alias_,
                 /*muni = */
                 polyline = ST_Union(rec_road.geom, student.roads.geom)
                 RETURNING * into return_intersect;
                 RETURN NEXT;
        End if;
    End Loop;
    Close cur_road;

    RETURN;

End; 
$$ Language plpgsql;

--< return the table>----------------------------------------------
SELECT create_intersections();
```

The `Roadname 1 & Roadname 2` should be generated from `roadnames` column from `ROADS` table, and the geometry for the intersection `ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)` should be generated from the `geom` column from `ROADS` table.
When I run it, it returns [no result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8cEn.png).

The table ROADS is something like this [road table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igJ8o.png),([geometry view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEcGD.png)):

```
Intid_     Muni    Alias_           Roadnames            geom
24581722   NULL    CR 52       Coopers Falls road        ...
24581723   NULL    CR 44       Rama road                 ...
```

Expected output should be similar to this one, but we need other fields to be filled as well.--->[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSEBW.png) ([geometry view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3jtF.png))

I also tried

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_intersections() 
     UPDATE student.intersect_roads AS $$
Declare
Begin
End
$$
```

Which is not working as well.

Comment: One issue I can see is that you're using != to compare geometries.  You need to use 'not st_equals(rec_road.geom,student.roads.geom)' instead.  There is also a typo near 'Then Update...' - it says student.raods.roadnames

Comment: Do I understand you right that you have a road coverage and everywhere two roads are intersecting you basically want a point with the two road names?